# In mule3, how to set a custom expression for choice-when router?

Tags: java, mule

I am new to Mule, I want to validate the timestamp and nonce parameter from URI for preventing the replay attack. I use choice-when router, when the timestamp and nonce is valid(the validation process is complex), forward the request to backend rest service, otherwise return error code and message. I found a lot of MEL usage for choice-when, but can I define a custom expression use java? and there is a example available?
URI example:

```
http://muledemo.org/ci2/ni/del?id=0xe413&timestamp=1376022133&nonce=a03ed9c
```

code snippets:

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
  <when expression="???how to call a java validator???">
  </when>
  <otherwise>
    <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
      <echo-component doc:name="Echo" />
      <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST"
        address="http://localhost:8081#[message.inboundProperties['http.request']]" doc:name="HTTP" />
    </processor-chain>
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

EDIT:

XML config:

```
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="replayAttackCheck" class="org.jamee.demo.mule.ReplayAttackCheck"/>
</spring:beans>

... ...

<when expression="#[replayAttackCheck.validate(payload)]">
  <expression-component doc:name="Check Required Params"><![CDATA[payload="{\"code\":\"PA002\", \"message\":\"timestamp or nonce is illegal\"}"]]>
  </expression-component>
</when>
```

Error log:

```
ERROR 2013-08-09 14:32:39,090 [[demo.router].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "replayAttackCheck.validate(payload)" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: HashMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. [Error: unresolvable property or identifier: replayAttackCheck]
[Near : {... replayAttackCheck.validate(pay ....}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct MEL syntax:

```
<when expression="#[app.registry.replayAttackCheck.validate(payload)]">
```

Comment: Yeah! It works, cool, thanks! Does the app.registry means the beans registered in spring?

Comment: Yes, plus extra ones added by Mule.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the fully qualified path

```
#[com.mulesoft.foo(payload, someFooVar)]
```

Alternatively you can define it globally for your app in your configuration and the use the "foo" function in your MEL expressions

```
<configuration doc:name="Config">
    <expression-language autoResolveVariables="false">
        <global-functions>
            def foo(fooVar){
            return com.mulesoft.foo(payload, fooVar);
            }                
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is com.mulesoft.foo? see my EDIT, I still get error.

Comment: foo is anything you want it to be ;) Can you try it again without using the bean? Use the full path in the MEL

Comment: I use <when expression="!replayAttackCheck.validate(payload)" evaluator="groovy">, it's OK now, here replayAttackCheck is a spring bean. The MEL can not express the complex logic. Anyway thanks!

Comment: Not true: MEL can express complex logic. It's built on MVEL which is very powerful: http://mvel.codehaus.org/Language+Guide+for+2.0